# GNU make differences in multiline variable declarations

Tags: variables, makefile

I read this question, and I was surprised it wasn't working:

[Why GNU Make canned recipe doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032935/why-gnu-make-canned-recipe-doesnt-work)

So I tried it myself and got the same results.  Here's an example makefile:

```
define foo
bar
baz
endef

define bar = 
foo
baz
endef

$(info foo: $(foo))
$(info bar: $(bar))

all:
```

And here's the output from running it:

```
$ make
foo: bar
baz
bar: 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

What's happening here?  The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) seems to indicate that these two variable declarations should be the same - what am I missing here?

Edit:

Some quotations from the manual that I was referring to:

> **[3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles)**
>
> ```
> define immediate
>   deferred
> endef
>
> define immediate =
>   deferred
> endef
> ```
>
> **[5.8 Defining Canned Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes)**
>
> Here is an example of defining a canned recipe:
>
> ```
>  define run-yacc =
>  yacc $(firstword $^)
>  mv y.tab.c $@
>  endef
> ```
>
> **[6.8 Defining Multi-Line Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multi_002dLine)**
>
> ... You may omit the variable assignment operator if you prefer. If omitted, make assumes it to be ‘=’ and creates a recursively-expanded variable...

As you can see, the canned recipes section *explicitly* uses the `=` case. I'm using GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: Just ran into this exact same problem, and `apt-get upgrade ; apt-get install make` was telling me that v3.81 was the latest so I was becoming furiouser and furiouser...  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the CHANGELOG in 3.82:

```
* read.c (do_define): Modify to allow assignment tokens (=, :=, etc.)
after a define, to create variables with those flavors.
```

It seems like using '=' isn't supported prior to that in **define** statements

Comment: Best answer! Concise quotation from an authoritative source that exactly explains the observed behavior. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

It's probably your `make` version.  I tested that makefile on my machine using make 3.81 in Cygwin and got:

```
$ make
foo: bar
baz
bar: 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I tested the same makefile using make 3.82 (native Windows build) and got:

```
C:\>C:\make\make.exe
foo: bar
baz
bar: foo
baz
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I believe the online `make` manual is for v3.82.

Comment: Well, that's an easy solution - thanks for pointing out my error!