# How do I process extremely long lists of files in a make recipe?

Tags: makefile

Because [GNU `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) allows variables to be as large as memory allows, it has no problem building massive dependency lists.  However, if you want to actually use these lists of files in a recipe (sequence of shell commands for building a target), you run into a problem: the command might exceed *the shell's* command line length limit, producing an error such as "Argument list too long".

For example, suppose I want to concatenate several files contained in the list `$(INPUTS)` to produce a file `combined.txt`.  Ordinarily, I could use:

```
combined.txt: $(INPUTS)
        cat $^ > $@
```

But if `$(INPUTS)` contains many thousands of files, as it does in my case, the call to `cat` is too long and fails.  Is there a way to get around this problem in general?  It's safe to assume that there exists some sequence of commands that have identical behaviour to the one enormous command -- in this case, a series of `cat` commands, one per input file, that use `>>` to append to `combined.txt` would work.  But how can `make` be persuaded to generate those commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In looking for the answer, about the best suggestion I could find was [to break up the list into a series of smaller lists and process them using shell `for` loops](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-5-SECT-6).  But you can't always do that, and even when you can it's a messy hack: for example, it's not obvious how to get the usual `make` behaviour of stopping as soon as a command fails.  Luckily, after much searching and experimentation, it turns out that a general solution does exist.

### Subshells and newlines

`make` recipes invoke a separate subshell for each line in the recipe.  This behaviour can be annoying and counterintuitive: for example, a `cd` command on one line will not affect subsequent commands because they are run in separate subshells.  Nevertheless it's actually what we need to get `make` to perform actions on very long lists of files.

Ordinarily, if you build a "multiline" list of files with a regular variable assignment that uses backslashes to break the statement over multiple lines, `make` removes all newlines:

```
# The following two statements are equivalent
FILES := a b c

FILES := \
a \
b \
c
```

However, using the `define` directive, it's possible to build variable values that contain newlines.  What's more, if you substitute such a variable into a recipe, each line will indeed be run using a separate subshell, so that for example running `make test` from `/home/jbloggs` with the makefile below (and assuming no file called `test` exists) will produce the output `/home/jbloggs`, because the effect of the `cd ..` command is lost when its subshell ends:

```
define CMDS
cd ..
pwd
endef

test:
        $(CMDS)
```

If we create a variable that contains newlines using `define`, it can be concatenated with other text as usual, and processed using all the usual `make` functions.  This, combined with the `$(foreach)` function, allows us to get what we want:

```
# Just a single newline!  Note 2 blank lines are needed.
define NL


endef

combined.txt: $(INPUTS)
        rm $@
        $(foreach f,$(INPUTS),cat $(f) >> $@$(NL))
```

We ask `$(foreach)` to convert each filename into a *newline-terminated* command, which will be executed in its own subshell.  For more complicated needs, you could instead write out the list of filenames to a file with a series of `echo` commands and then use [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs).

### Notes

- The `define` directive is described as optionally taking a `=`, `:=` or `+=` token on the end of the first line to determine which [variable flavour](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) is to be created -- but note that that only works on versions of GNU `make` 3.82 and up!  You may well be running the popular version 3.81, as I was, which silently assigns nothing to the variable if you add one of these tokens, leading to much frustration.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033181/gnu-make-differences-in-multiline-variable-declarations) for more.
- All recipe lines must begin with a literal tab character, not the 8 spaces I have used here.

Comment: Ad last note: Actually, it's possible to redefine the prefix in GNU Make, so you can have recipes starting with 8 spaces, 4 spaces, `>`, `%`, whatever (I don't remember the exact incantation off the top of my head, but it's somewhere in the manual).