# Makefile - argument list too long, but only in some configurations

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm trying to reproduce a situation which happens only in some machines. To reproduce it, I create a directory with 2000 files:

```
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test
for f in $(seq 1 2000); do touch $f.txt; done
```

Then I use the following Makefile (simplified from the real use case):

```
FILES:=$(shell find . -name '*.txt')

%.done: %.txt
    @echo "done $@"

toolong:
    @$(foreach file,$(sort $(FILES)), \
        if $(MAKE) $(file); \
        then echo "did $(file)" >> $@; \
        else echo "failed $(file)" >> $@; fi; )
```

Running `make` produces, unsurprisingly, an error:

```
make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039811) presents a solution which does work. However, I need to understand exactly why this error *does not happen* on my colleagues' computers. I tried the following things:

- Increasing stack limit (`ulimit -s` gives the same result on both machines, 8192, and increasing it does not change anything);
- Checking `getconf ARG_MAX` (2097152 in both machines);
- Checking `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` (131072 in both machines);
- Using a different shell (`zsh` is being used in both machines; I also tried `bash`, `dash` and `sh`, via `export SHELL=<shell> make`, and also by replacing the symlink `/bin/sh -> /bin/bash` with a link to `dash`).

Finally, I tried recompiling Make from source, and realized that, even when I compile the same version of Make (4.1) in my Ubuntu test machine, I get the same behavior as I had in my Fedora, that is, the error "argument list too long".

`make --version` only shows a single difference between them:

Version from the `apt` package:

> GNU Make 4.1
>   Built for x86_64-**pc**-linux-gnu

Version compiled from source (`./configure && make`):

> GNU Make 4.1
>   Built for x86_64-**unknown**-linux-gnu

I even tried compiling [make-dfsg](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/make-dfsg/4.1-9.1), which results in an **identical** `make --version`, but the result is the same as with my other manually-compiled make.

By increasing the number of files on Ubuntu, I managed to identify that the actual limits in the size of the generated command line are:

- Fedora or Arch Linux (both with Make 4.2.1), or Ubuntu with manually-compiled Make 4.1: 128 KB (~1200 files);
- Debian Sid or Ubuntu, both with Make 4.1 installed from `apt` package: 2 MB (~19300 files).

I'd really like to understand (1) why this difference exists, and (2) how could I compile Make to obtain the higher limit, so that I can have the exact same behavior on both machines.

Comment: did you check environment length, seems limitation is over environment+argument length

Comment: may be useful [cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility/110301#110301)

Comment: Your simplified Makefile fragment doesn't contain any /bin/sh call, only gmake internal functions. Where exactly is the line with the arg list too long? Apart from that, run your make with a minimal environment, such as `env -i HOME=$HOME PATH=$PATH gmake ...` to exclude that the environment size is the culprit.

Comment: @Jens: The actual makefile does call other commands, however this is the simplest version I got that produces the exactly same error message I had in the original makefile. If you have a non-Debian machine, copy-pasting the first code block in my question, then copying the second one inside a `Makefile` (replacing spaces with tab when necessary) should result in that exact error message. Replace 2000 with 20000, and you should also be able to reproduce it on a Debian-based machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your recipe expands as a one-line shell compound command (because of the line ending backslashes). And this line is probably way too long. Did you check what it looks like (the shell compound command) on all machines? I suggest that you wrap it in `$(info...)`:

```
toolong:
    @$(info $(foreach file,$(sort $(FILES)), \
        if $(MAKE) $(file); \
        then echo "did $(file)" >> $@; \
        else echo "failed $(file)" >> $@; fi; ))
```

and see if the output is the same on your machine and on the others. If, for any reason, yours is longer, it could be the explanation. Else it must be a OS difference...

Note: you could have one rule per target, instead of one single rule with a huge recipe for all.

Note: your recipe (independently from its fantastic length) does nothing useful. As the files already exist and do not have pre-requisites, all your sub-make calls will just tell you that the files are up-to-date.

Comment: That's a very good remark. However, strangely, when I use `info`, in both machines I get the exact same output, and none complain about the line being too large. I `diff`ed the output and it was identical.

About the utility of the recipe itself, I know it's not very useful, but the actual recipe does something useful, I just simplified it because the bug is unrelated to the recipe, and I wanted it to be easy to retry, without having to erase files after each test.

Comment: @anol It is not strange that none complain about the line length: it is processed by make only, not by the shell. If the outputs are identical, it must be an OS difference but guessing which one with no access to the machines seems difficult.

Comment: I just posted an edit: the limit seems to be 128 KB on Fedora and 2 MB on Ubuntu. In case that could help tracking where it comes from...

Comment: Did you account for the environment size? What does `env | wc -c` return on the different machines?

Comment: `env | wc -c` reports 4470 on my Fedora, and 2654 on my Ubuntu. But one of my colleagues had it report less than 1200 on his Arch Linux and it still failed, just like in my Fedora. To me, the difference seems too small to be relevant.

Comment: @anol Agreed. It really looks like a kernel limit. But if you are sure of your `ARG_MAX` I do not see what it can be. Did you try to add `getconf ARG_MAX` as the first line of your recipe, just to be 100% sure?

Comment: As I just posted, the issue seems elsewhere: compiling the same code that is supposed to be the one from the Ubuntu package, on the Ubuntu machine, changes the behavior. Maybe I should rewrite the entire question as a source replication issue.