# Makefile error When I want to build the project for android

Tags: android, qt, makefile, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I have `SubDirs` project with a `Qt Quick Application` and several c++ library project that is statically linked to Qt Application.But I have a problem that is in below.

> Qt version: Qt 5.14.2
>
> Qt Kit for android is not showing any problem.
>
> I don't have any problem in windows ,And the project will run on windows with no error
>
> I able to run simple Qt Quick Application(Scroll,Stack and other that is in template) on my android device but When I add the c++ libraries and add link to application this error will happen.

**Error**

```
:-1: error: [install_target] Error 1
```

**Compile output**

```
12:18:32: The process "D:\SDK\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
12:18:32: Starting: "D:\SDK\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" "INSTALL_ROOT=D:\build-MySubdirProName-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_14_2_for_Android-Debug\android-build" install
cd JooyaAndroid\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.14.2\android\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile D:\QtProjects\JooyaAndroid\JooyaAndroid.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" "ANDROID_ABIS=armeabi-v7a" ) && D:/SDK/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/build-MySubdirProName-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_14_2_for_Android-Debug/JooyaAndroid'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1068: install_target] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/build-MySubdirProName-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_14_2_for_Android-Debug/JooyaAndroid'
make: *** [Makefile:74: sub-JooyaAndroid-install_subtargets] Error 2
12:18:34: The process "D:\SDK\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project MySubdirProName(kit: Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.2 for Android))
When executing step "Copy application data"
12:18:34: Elapsed time: 00:33.
```

I think the error is related to `Makefile` file.Can any one say How can I solve this problem?

**Edit**

I have inserted some line of Makefile for more information about the error:

```
1065 ####### Install
1066 
1067 install_target: all FORCE
1068    @if not exist C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic mkdir C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic & if not exist C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic exit 1
1069    $(QINSTALL) $(TARGET) C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic\$(TARGET)
1070    $(RANLIB) C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic\$(TARGET)
1071 
1072 uninstall_target: FORCE
1073    -$(DEL_FILE) C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic\$(TARGET)
1074    -$(DEL_DIR) C:$(INSTALL_ROOT:@msyshack@%=%)\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\generic
```

And more information About Line 1068 is that,There is several folder in `C:\Qt\5.14.2\android\plugins\` but the `generic` folder is not exists.

**Edit 2**

After several days of trying, I have achieved a small success.I can build `subdirs` project that have one `C++ Library` and one `Qt Quick Application` for Android as follows:

1-In C++ Library `pro` file I had first below configuration And I build the project but I had above error:

```
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
    summer.cpp

HEADERS += \
    summer.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

2- Then I chaged the `pro` file like below:

```
CONFIG += dll
```

3- I pressed the build button and Project Successfully Build And Apk File is in output folder

But I don't know What is happeing.Given the above, I want to know how to solve my problem.

When I change the `Config += dll` without building project with `Config += staticlib` the below error is appearing and project will not build without first `staticlib` and then `dll` config!

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target 'D:\QtProjects\MyQtProjects\build-FirstSubdirProject-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_QtForAndroid_32ca93-Debug\FirstQtQuickApp\..\MyFirstLibrary\libMyFirstLibrary.a', needed by 'libFirstQtQuickApp_armeabi-v7a.so'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Apparently there is something wrong with `D:/QtProjects/build-HokmBazi-Android_ARMv7-Release/JooyaQuickDesign` directory. Maybe slashes should be changed in configuration (to backslash) - it's windows.

Comment: The error message helpfully tells you that the error occurs on line 1068 of the Makefile in directory `D:/build-MySubdirProName-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_14_2_for_Android-Debug/JooyaAndroid`.  I presume that this makefile was written by qmake.  We cannot tell you anything more without more information.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited the question,if you want more infomation ,I can edit the question again.tank you

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have edited the question for the second time. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: @mohsen, The edits are helpful and appropriate, but they reveal that your particular case is too thick with details from your Windows / msys build environment and from qmake for me to help.  The bounty is likely to attract some attention, though.  I do find it suspicious that "`@msyshack@`" appears all over the makefile.  It makes me think that something may have gone wrong with qmake building that file, but I'm not confident of that assessment, nor do I have suggestions for how to investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution,When I create a new C++ Library Project in Qt Creator,It will create a pro file that have below content

```
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
    testlibrary.cpp

HEADERS += \
    testlibrary.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

I have deleted the below content from pro file So the problem is removed

```
# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Check your filenames. Maybe due to too long path error file (source or object). Such error is in windows only, for unix-based systems, there is no such restriction.

This error also caused by too long argument list ([e.g. too long objects to be linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039811/how-do-i-process-extremely-long-lists-of-files-in-a-make-recipe))

Comment: No ,This not helped,

Comment: @mohsen Try building under an Ubunto VM with android studio. If succeeded, this means some platform problem (such as one of above)

Comment: No,I mentioned in question.I able to build and run simple qt quick application for android and it will run on android device,So If path and name have problem so this simple application should not build and run

Comment: @mohsen Ok, sorry. If some folder didn't exist and causing error, this means some step before that didn't complete successfully (or you have forgotten to put it)

Comment: I have test the build and run with smaller path => I Changed `D:/build-MySubdirProName-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_14_2_for_Android-Debug` to `D:/build-MySubdirProName-AD`

Comment: @mohsen Also you are building ok with no libs (only qt), but after that when you add your libs it fails. This can happen if linker is invoked with too many object files at ones to merge in a library (so or a). This can occur for very large projects with thousands of object files linked at ones

Comment: if there is problem So ,Why my application is build and run on windows?

Comment: @mohsen It builds with small source code, not large file count.

Comment: If you don't know, source is first COMPILED to object files (every 1 file = 1 object file). Then next, all OBJECT files ARE LINKED together to form a library

Comment: That's why I recommand you to build in VM with ubunto and see if it fails or not