# Why does my makefile variable not work when using the "define" directive?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU Make 3.81. The following makefile works correctly:

```
name=lucas

all: test

.PHONY: test
test: 
    echo $(name) # outputs variable correctly
```

But when I try defining the variable using the "define" directive it stops working:

```
define name =
lucas
endef

all: test

.PHONY: test
test: 
    echo $(name)
```

Why doesn't this second version work? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Found [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033181/gnu-make-differences-in-multiline-variable-declarations). Looks like it's a version thing. The `=` sign is recognized in define statements only since version 3.82 apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your `test` target doesn't have a `'\t'` before `echo $(name)`.
When I copied and pasted your makefile code I saw that, and I don't think it's
the markdown language because I checked other questions with makefiles and it worked there.

Comment: I'm using version GNU Make 3.81. I'm wondering if the version might be my issue. I'm completely at a loss, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033181/gnu-make-differences-in-multiline-variable-declarations). Looks like it's a version thing. The = sign isn't recognized in define statements for versions prior to 3.82 apparently.

Comment: You mean, "_the = sign isn't recognized in `define` statements prior version 3.82_", I guess.