# Is there an elegant way to control permissions for directories created by "install -D"?

Tags: makefile

I am using `[/usr/bin/]install` in a Makefile to copy some binaries into my `$HOME` directory. My umask is set to 700.

The problem is that I am using `install -D -m 700` to install the binaries and the parent directory is created with permissions of 755 and not 700:

```
$ umask
077
$ ls
$ touch hello
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw------- 1 emuso emuso 0 Apr  5 13:15 hello
$ install -D -m 700 hello $PWD/this/is/hello
$ ls -ld this
drwxr-xr-x 3 emuso emuso 4096 Apr  5 13:17 this
$ ls -lR this 
this:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 emuso emuso 4096 Apr  5 13:17 is

this/is:
total 0
-rwx------ 1 emuso emuso 0 Apr  5 13:17 hello
```

I want that the directories `this` and `is` get permissions 700 instead of 755.

Solutions that come to my mind are:

1. using `install -d -m 700` to create the directory structure by hand.
2. using `chmod` to fix permissions manually.

The major drawback for the first solution is that I have a directory structure, which I would have to travel and create by hand.

So my question is: Is there an elegant way to control permissions for directories created by "install -D"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve does not seem possible with a single invocation to `install` only, so you might have to resort to a combination of `mkdir` and `install`. Depending on your exact situation, you might be able to take advantage of a [canned recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html), using something like this:

```
define einstall
test -d "$(dir $@)" || mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
install -m 700 $< $@
endef

some/new/test/hello: hello
    $(einstall)
```

If you plan to play around with canned recipes with make v3.81 or older, please make sure to read this answer to [Why GNU Make canned recipe doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033043/1380680)